# Angular app with external display

Tags: angularjs, chromecast

I am developing a simple angular app with IoT which is detecting the temperature of a sensor.

All I want to do is, when the temperature is above 50, I display a message in my tv. What would be the best way to do this?  My tv screen is connected to Chromecast, I have raspberry pi (If needed) and I can if needed connect a computer to the tv screen.

PS : The angular app is on my phone, and I want to display the message on the tv screen.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `<div ng-if="temp > 50">Hot!</div>`

Comment: The thing is : the angular app is on my phone, and I want to display the message on the tv. My apologizes for not being so clear

Comment: Then i've no idea... Sorry

Comment: What about using the pi to create a web server and make an http call from your angular app when the 50 degree condition is met?

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague:
(1) Are you assuming that your TV is always on?
(2) Do you want to show the temperature as an overlay on top of whatever TV/Chromecast is showing or you want to have a dedicated app on TV?
(3) Do you want this to work only if you are at home, on the same wifi network or even when that is not the case?